# Null refference exception on mysql connection with c# on .isPasswordExpired and server thread,version

Tags: c#, mysql, database, nullreferenceexception

It's really odd. I just use the default connection everything, it is the first time i get this error been trying for hours to fix it and find solution online with no success. I have this code:

```
class DbConnect
{


    //get values of name and customerid using the bracelet id ( a equijoin using customer, ticketpurchase and ticket)
    //every ticket is assigned a bracelet id - and i have 6 bracelets to add so also 6 dummy profiles in database

     //method to look for customerid using bracelet id and return only one string
     public int CustomerId(string braceletId)
    {
         String str = @"server=localhost;database=dbi340001;userid=xxxxxxxxxxx;password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;";

        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(str);

        try
        {
            con.Open(); //open the connection
            MessageBox.Show("welcome");
            return 1;
        }
        catch (MySqlException err) //We will capture and display any MySql errors that will occur
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: " + err.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (con != null)
            {
                con.Close(); //safely close the connection
            }
        } //remember to safely close the connection after accessing the database

        return 0;
```

It's a really simple code which i call from another class and i just wrote it to see if the connection will happen with default code. The error is null refference exceptions on conn.isPasswordExpired and conn.ServerThread adn conn.ServerVersion which are all parameters with only get from the mysqlconnection object so it really doesn't make any sence. 
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The is no longer an occurrence of con.isPasswordExpired in the edited question. So what is the error now and where does it occur?

Comment: what i was saying about that was is that i didn't compile that part so its sitll the same error as before basically ispasswordexpired serverthread and serverversion are nulls everything else is fine but the connection cant open

Comment: The code now looks pretty much correct. Go ahead and run it and see what error you get. Otherwise, this question no longer makes sense because you are not telling us which is the actual error for the current code snippet.

Comment: its stil the same error the three parameters arent set and are null

Comment: On which statement does it occur?

Comment: when it makes the mysqlconnection object 'con' when i look it while debugging it shows that it has parsed all parameters and these three are red with x's on them and it says nullrefference exception which is odd and strangest part is i had this issue on the one laptop and now i tried it on another and the issue is still there , so im not sure what to do tommorow i can try with third computer maybe

Answer (score 0):

`con.IsPasswordExpired;` is called right after `MySqlConnection con = null;`

Obviously, `con` is still `null` when you call `con.IsPasswordExpired;`

You should consider moving that statement anywhere AFTER `con = new MySqlConnection(str);`

Comment: it still gives the same errors when i go to the conn object it still has red x's on these three parameters this is the code now :

Comment: @user5780143 Don't post code that long in comments. Consider editing the question istead. It's not even readable.

Comment: i think there litteraly nothing wrong with the code and its just some .dll error or something internal right now

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
```

So that it will initialize the object `con`, then It will not be `null`.

Comment: the issue is now resolved there was a domain issue becuase the host had 2 ports and i didnt specify which and whence the problems occured, thanks for the assistance though